# Alias doesn't work in script with #!/usr/bin/env php

Tags: php, bash, env

I've some PHP scripts which are starting with `#!/usr/bin/env php`. The default interpreter is PHP 4.4, but the scripts need PHP 5.3, so I created an alias in `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias php="/usr/local/bin/php5-53LATEST-CLI"
```

Thus calling `php -v` shows me 5.3 but `#!/usr/bin/env php` uses still 4.4. I wont change the scripts. So how can I get PHP 5.3 with `#!/usr/bin/env php`?

Comment: You will change the scripts. Or get rid of PHP 4.4.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`/usr/bin/env php` looks for an executable named `php` in the current `$PATH`; it pays no attention to aliases, shell functions, etc. If you want it to execute php v5.3, you have to put that version in a directory under the name `php`, and put that directory in your `PATH` somewhere before the directory that contains version 4.4. Maybe something like this:

```
mkdir /usr/local/bin/php-overrides
ln -s /usr/local/bin/php5-53LATEST-CLI /usr/local/bin/php-overrides/php
```

...then add

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin/php-overrides:$PATH"
```

to your `~/.bash_profile` (or other appropriate startup script).